# TreeView - only allow edit of some nodes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

In the WinForms `TreeView` class is there a way to only allow some nodes to be edited? I know I can cancel the edit on the `AfterLabelEdit` event, but I want it to not even allow the edit so people don't try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BeforeLabelEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforelabeledit(v=vs.110).aspx) event occurs before the tree node label text is edited and in this event you can cancel editing by setting [`CancelEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nodelabelediteventargs.canceledit(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the event argument to `true` based on some criteria. For example:

```
private void treeView1_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Text == "Node1")
        e.CancelEdit = true;
}
```